# How to model an article recommender as a Q-learning problem in Python

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, q-learning, recommendation-engine

I want to implement an article recommender using Q-learning in Python. Our dataset has, for instance, four categories of articles, including health, sports, news, and lifestyle, and 10 articles for each category (40 articles in total). The idea is to show some random articles to the user (e.g., five articles and they can be from any category) and to receive his/her feedback. Then, the agent learns the preference (i.e., the category of the article) of the user and recommends some relevant articles again.

To formulate this as a RL problem, I know that I should define actions, states, and a reward function. Having studied some articles, I came up with:

Action: recommending an article;

State: I'm not very clear about this, but what I learned from other articles is the state can be:

a) a trail of recently studied articles by the user;
 b) User interest (not sure how this can be a state);

Reward: A very simple reward. It can be +1 if the user studies the recommended article or -1 for a useless recommendation.

For the Q-learning part, I'm not sure how I should make the Q-table containing the states as rows and actions as the columns.

For other simple RL problems, like MountainCar, developing the q-table is not that difficult, but the way that states are not very clear here has confused me.

I'd really appreciate if you can help me with suggesting a solution to formulate this as a RL problem and few lines of code to inspire me how to start to code it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure about the states you could use multi-armed bandit algorithms where you just take actions and get rewards.

If you want to use a trail of recently studied articles by the user, then you can use contextual-bandit algorithms which takes into account the state.
Because the episode is only for one step, it is more of contextual bandits problem than reinforcement learning.

Although, you could use something like this to train.

```
state = env.reset()
state_buffer = []
# now append the history of the user in state_buffer list
# so now state_buffer has the most recent five states observed
# here state can be a vector of size four with entries being one if that article was read by the user in that time-step
# if the previous article read by the user is health then [1,0,0,0]
# if the previous article read by the user is sports then [0,1,0,0]
# action is which article to show next

# run for 1000 episodes
for i in range(1000):
    action = policy.select_action(state_buffer)
    next_state,reward,done,info = env.step(action)
    policy.update()
    state_buffer.pop(0)
    state_buffer.append(next_state)
# NOTE: you will have to implement policy class which has a function approximator (neural-network)
# policy.update() does the Q-learning update
```

Also, you could go through [this](https://blog.insightdatascience.com/multi-armed-bandits-for-dynamic-movie-recommendations-5eb8f325ed1d) blog.